# Get <p> between two <h2> (one of them without identifier) with Xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I've just started working with HtmlAgilityPack in C# and I have to use Xpath (I do not have any idea about that).
I need to get all p between two `<h2>`, I know the text in the first `<h2>`, but the other one is dynamic, I do not know what contains.

```html
<div>
     <h2><span>Location</span></h2>
     <p>Hi</p>
     <p>It's ok.</p>
     <p>Bye</p>
     <h2><span>{Dynamic text}</span></h2>
     <p>I do not know.</p>
     <h2><span>Summary</span></h2>
     <p>The end.</p>
</div>
```

How can I take all `<p>` between `<h2> > span['Location']` and the next `<h2>` (Again, I do not know what contains).

I tested:

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h2[span='Location'] and following-sibling::h2]

//p[count(preceding-sibling::h2[span='Location'])=1]
```

Both test with same result: All `<p>`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to look at it: what is between two marks is the same as the intersection between those following the first mark and those preceding the second mark. For intersection in XPath 1.0 we use the Kaysian Method. In your case

```
/div/h2[span='Location']/following-sibling::h2[1]/preceding-sibling::*[
   count(.|/div/h2[span='Location']/following-sibling::*)
   = count(/div/h2[span='Location']/following-sibling::*)
]
```